# test class for trigger not working - Error: without querying the requested field

Tags: trigger, unit-test

i have done a simple trigger, running so far in sandbox, but then i tried to write a test class, but this is not working, it returns the following error:

> Error Message  System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.Source_Details__c
>
> Stack Trace    Class.TestClassOppCaseStore.TestClassOppCaseStore_trigger: line 61, column 1

maybe important to know, the field Source_Details__c in Opp is formular field related to the account from the Opp

Here is the trigger

```
trigger update_related_Supplier on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
     if(opp.Source_Details__c != null){
           Account[] acc = [Select Id from Account where Name = :opp.Source_Details__c] ;
         if(acc.size() > 0){
             opp.related_Partner_Supplier__c = acc[0].Id;}
         else  {            opp.related_Partner_Supplier__c = null;
         }}}}
```

and here is the testclass

```
@IsTest
public class TestClassOppCaseStore {
static testMethod void TestClassOppCaseStore_trigger(){
Account a = new Account(Name = 'testAccount',
                        BillingPostalCode = '83059',
                       BillingCountry = 'Deutschland',
                       Source_Details__c = 'Düren (Saturn)');
insert a; 
Lead l = new Lead (LastName = 'Musterhausen',
                   Country = 'Deutschland',
                   Company = 'MeierEisen',
                   PostalCode = '12457',
                   LeadSource = 'Import',
                   Status = 'new');
insert l;

Event k = new Event (Subject = 'Testing',
                     WhoId = l.Id,
                     StartDateTime = date.today(),
                    EndDateTime = date.today());
    insert k;

Event m = new Event (Subject = 'Testing',
                     WhatId = a.Id,
                     StartDateTime = date.today(),
                    EndDateTime = date.today());
    insert m;

Task t = new Task (Subject = 'Demotermin',
                   WhatId = a.Id);
 insert t;

Task u = new Task (Subject = 'Demotermin',
                   WhoId = l.Id);
 insert u;

    Pricebook2 d = new Pricebook2 (Name = 'Standard');
insert d;
Product2 e =new Product2 (Name = 'Top AG',
                          VK_netto__c = 12);
insert e;
        Opportunity g = new Opportunity (Name = 'testOpp',
                                  AccountId = a.Id,
                                 Amount = 250,
                                 StageName = 'new',
                                 CloseDate = date.today());
    insert g;
    update a;
CKSW_BASE__Service__c serv = new CKSW_BASE__Service__c (Opportunity__c = g.Id,
                                                       CKSW_BASE__Account__c = a.Id,
                                                       CKSW_BASE__Status__c = 'new');
insert serv;
Case c = new Case (Subject = g.Name);
insert c;
g = [SELECT Account.Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :g.Id];
System.AssertEquals(a.Id, g.AccountID);
a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :g.Source_Details__c];
System.AssertEquals(a.Id, g.related_Partner_Supplier__c);
a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :c.Account_Source_Details__c];
System.AssertEquals(a.Id, c.related_Partner_Supplier__c);}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect one (not included `Source_Details__c`) :

```
g = [SELECT Account.Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :g.Id];
```

Correct one:

```
g = [SELECT Account.Id, Source_Details__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :g.Id];
System.AssertEquals(a.Id, g.AccountID);
```

Since you are using `Source_Details__c` in the next line, so it must be retrieved from Opportunity SOQL before using it.

```
a = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :g.Source_Details__c];
```

Comment: Thx, that helped a lot, unfortunately, i do face another issue now, new Error is "System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.Source_Details__c"  Thing is here, the field 'Source_Details__c' is a formula field, which will be filled with the value from the account field 'Source_Details__c'. Does the test class not run formula field in the test?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here but I would think this line

```
g = [SELECT Account.Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :g.Id];
```

needs to be

```
g = [SELECT Account.Id, Source_Details__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :g.Id];
```